# Where can I find a database with a lot of high-resolution CIE L*a*b* images?

Tags: image, download, cielab

I'm looking for a database with a lot of high-resolution CIE L*a*b* images. Do you know where can I find it? I found RGB images only.

Comment: Maybe a "why?" could help. Are you sure you see only RGB? JPEG is often encoden in a more similar way to CIELab then RGB (YUU, YCC, ...are not so far from CIELab with different scaling factors). Video is nearly never RGB. -- And BYT the CIELab is just a colour encoding, so you can change it. Strange question.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many formats that are able to store images in CIE Lab colourspace, in fact the only one I know of is **TIF** and I believe CIE Lab colourspace is actually only an extension that not all software is able to handle.

I can only suggest you find a suitable database in another format and convert it yourself. You can do that painlessly with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, to convert a single hi-res PNG file to CIE Lab colourspace and save as TIF, you could run this in Terminal:

```
magick input.png -colorspace Lab result.tif
```

If you had hundreds of PNGs, you could do them all in one go with:

```
magick mogrify -colorspace Lab -format TIF *png
```

---

If you are using **ImageMagick** v6 or older, use:

```
convert input.png -colorspace Lab result.tif        # for single image
mogrify -colorspace Lab -format TIF *png            # for multiple images
```

Comment: But if I convert an RGB image to Lab I don't get any difference because all the colors will be the same as the RGB color space. The RGB is included in the CIELAB color space so the conversion has no sense...